# Wordpress more between values in query

Tags: php, wordpress

I have price search in wp query like that

```
$args=array("post_type"=>"nemovitosti",'meta_query'=> array("key"=>"cena","value"=>array(0,1000),'type' => 'numeric','compare' => 'BETWEEN'),'offset'=>0,'posts_per_page'=>-1);
```

But what I need is find between more values like 0-1000, 5000-20000, 50000-200000 for key "cena".

How I can use wp_query for same key with another between values?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try with this:

```
<?php

$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'nemovitosti',
    'offset'         => 0,
    'posts_per_page' => 999,
    'meta_query'     => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'cena',
            'value'   => array( 0, 1000),
            'type'    => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'cena',
            'value'   => array( 5000, 20000),
            'type'    => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'cena',
            'value'   => array( 50000, 200000),
            'type'    => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
        ),
    ),
);
```

This should target either prices between 0-1000, or 5000-20000 or 50000-200000.

Read more here [WP_Query Custom_Field_Parameters](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).